# Jetty Server - How to find information about http connectors in use from JMX

Tags: jetty, jmx

I am using a Jetty Server (7.6.8) and I would like to be able from the JMX in the JVM, to see which http connectors is available in the Jetty server. So I would be able to figure our what the http port number is, as well for https etc.

I have looked at all the JMX MBean that the Jetty server exposes when you start it using JMX with:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -jar start.jar  etc/jetty-jmx.xml
```

But I cannot find any information about the http port. I know 8080 is in use as thats the default port and also what is being logged

```
2013-03-04 11:55:54.260:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

If I look at the server MBean: org.eclipse.jetty.server:type=server,id=0
Then I can see connectors as an JMX attribute, but its value is always null.

Anyone know how to grab the connector details from JMX with Jetty?

I also look at Jetty 8.1.9.v20130131 and I could not find these information neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the instructions with jetty 7.6.9

1. Configure `start.ini`

   1. Make sure you have `jmx` in the `OPTIONS` line.
   2. Make sure you have `etc/jetty-jmx.xml` present and specified *before* the `etc/jetty.xml` line
   3. add `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` to the top of the file
2. Start jetty

   `$ java -jar start.jar`
3. Run `jconsole`
4. In jconsole, connect to `start.jar`
5. Open the MBeans tab
6. Navigate to `org.eclipse.jetty.server` > `server` > `0` > `Attributes` > `connectors`

   You will see that connectors value will likely have something like this ...

   `org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio:type=selectchannelconnector,id=0`

   Which is an `ObjectName` reference to another part of the JMX tree.
7. Now navigate to the specific connector at `org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio` > `selectchannelconnector` > `0` > `Attributes` to see the details

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, and great step by step solution. I can now see the connectors in the JMX tree, and figure out the http/https port numbers.